# Navigation Bar Buttons Hidden Issue Using With TabBarViewController

Tags: ios, xcode6, uinavigationbar, uitabbar, uinavigationitem

I have recently started iOS application development.
So, i hope every iOS developer will help me.

**Problem :**

I have been using uinavigationview controller with uitabviewcontroller.
I have some uinavigation bar 2 right Buttons and 2 left buttons.

i need all these on all my tabs except one where i need to hide all.

but it will not hide all.

**After doing google**

i found two line code.

```
self.navigationItem.rightButtonItems=nil;
self.navigationItem.leftButtonItems=nil;
```

But it still showing all.

Thank you in advance for your precious time to see my problem and help me out.

Comment: why don't you try hiding complete navigation bar instead?

Comment: no there is a title on navigation that i have to show.

Comment: try with self.navigationController.topViewController and then navigation bar ,items in that.

Comment: @johnykumar will you please write a code line that help me out.